# Why is the turnstile called \vdash?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

Why is the turnstile $\vdash$ called "vdash"?

I'm sure the explanation is simple (is it just that it's vertical bar followed by a dash?), but I can't seem to find anything "official" online.

Comment: Hmmm... there is a WP page for it too:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it's vertical (then) dash `|-` as opposed to dashv (`-|`), Vdash (`||-`) Vvdash (`|||-`)  dashVdash (`-|-`) etc.  (these names are all in `unicode-math` and most also in `amssymb`

Comment: You really mean `amsfonts`/`amssymb`.  When names were assigned, short names were desired, and since the meaning may be different in different math areas, a descriptive approach was chosen.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes edited to amssymb, thanks

Comment: Ah, I notice that the wikipedia page linked by Thruston (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29) says the answer two sentences below where I looked. Thank you for the clarification – sorry I missed the obvious answer when I originally looked.